# flutter-upgrade broke my app

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am building an App using flutter, and it was working fine until I chose to run the `flutter-upgrade` command to upgrade my installation. Now a part of the app where I use a ListView is completely broken, and after trying to access the part of the app where the ListView is used, the rest of the app breaks and widgets stop rendering properly.

Everything was working fine before I upgraded my flutter installation, and I need to have the app finished by next week.

Here's the log:

```
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: not implemented
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#d393e relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#91fed relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#f8b9f relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#907c6 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#82c34 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#c0929 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#cb75f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#f4dd1 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#21ed2 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bfca1 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#287cb relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#c0494 relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#aeb03 relayoutBoundary=up22 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#e84fd relayoutBoundary=up21 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#9eefe relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#21c05 relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#206e4 relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#97115 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#a3dfd relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#b037b relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#73cda relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#3820e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#24f8f relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#2dc3c relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#3a18a relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#32415 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderExcludableScrollSemantics#4231f relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#25954 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#f9945 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#d55b6 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#55872 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#14d29 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#da286 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#ac1fb relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#daa7e relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#4e74a relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4850): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
```

Any help you can provide is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

PS: Just in case, the code where the ListView is implemented can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sofferjacob/0b01776973467abf3e7ea4866994fff7).

My Flutter version:
Flutter 0.5.7-pre.62 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7ac183794b (27 hours ago) • 2018-07-06 15:21:29 -0700
Engine • revision 6fe748490d
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.63.0.flutter-4c9689c1d2

I am currently on the master channel, but the app still breaks with the latest build from the beta channel.

Comment: The "another exception was thrown" means this failure is probably the result of an earlier failure.  Can you restart your app and post the first part of the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downgrade flutter at any moment by cloning Flutter repository at the desired version. Then running `flutter doctor`.

Comment: Adding to this answer: you can also select a custom channel with `flutter channel beta`. I know that the beta channel is currently on 0.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer, you can use the `dev` branch instead of `master`. As more and more people contribute to Flutter, `master` can become unstable. `dev` is typically a week behind master and is a lot more stable for development.